# How to calculate the sum of two columns values based on different conditions and scenarios in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I need to calculate the sum of units and sum of revenue in the below table based on the following condition:

If Code = a and code = any other then calculate the sum of units and revenue under Category1

If code = b and (code = c or code =d) and (code not a ) and code = any other calculate the sum under Category2

If code = b and ( code not c ) and (code not d ) and (code not a ) and code = any other calculate the sum under Category3

Note that the sum of units should calculate only the average sum ( meaning for ID = 1, the sum of units of this particular ID is 2 ).

The sum of revenue is the sum of amounts in all lines, for instance: sum of revenue for ID=1 is 2890

| D | Units | Code | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | b | 500 |
| 1 | 2 | c | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | d | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | e | 2000 |
| 1 | 2 | g | 50 |
| 2 | 3 | b | 60 |
| 2 | 3 | b | 700 |
| 2 | 3 | c | 400 |
| 2 | 3 | d | 300 |
| 2 | 3 | b | 100 |
| 2 | 3 | g | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | f | 212 |
| 2 | 3 | g | 236 |
| 2 | 3 | f | 254 |
| 3 | 5 | b | 20 |
| 3 | 5 | g | 30 |
| 3 | 5 | i | 55 |
| 3 | 5 | h | 60 |
| 3 | 5 | m | 80 |

I tried using filter function but did not work

Comment: Sorry, but this question makes no sense. code = b and (code = c or code =d) .  The code cannot both be B and CorD at the same time. The same for the rest of your request.  If you ever come back to adjust your question, post the sample desired output so someone can check

Comment: It is repeated rows as you see based on the ID ,meaning code can be in a group of values

Comment: Maybe someone else can help you. To me it is confusing, and not helped by the fact that you left off desired output.